# How to quote and justify an eCommerce solution to a non-technical customer

Tags: price, estimation, project-management

I am a web freelancer with .NET experience, and I am about to give my first eCommerce solution quote to a new client. The client is looking to sell their product online with eBay, integrate with Amazon, utilize various payment gateways, add analytics, etc. I have examined some out-of-the-box products such as uCommerce, but a solution like that would cost between 2500 to 5000 euros per year.

The quotation going to be full price (i.e. not hourly charged).

Questions:

1. How do you decide the quote?
2. If I go for a product like uCommerce, do I exclude the subscription charges from my quote? That is, would I quote £X for consultancy + 2500 euros for uCommerce, or should I quote for the first year with everything included for the first year (which is adding above two)?
3. I can see that this will cost me £X, but when I see other leased eCommerce solutions, my quote looks ridiculously expensive in comparison (or theirs so unbelievably cheap). Why are those online solutions (1-and-1, GoDaddy, etc.) so cheap?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Decide the quote based on the job, and amount of work-hour it would take. Even-though you are not working per hour basis.**

*Things to remember : 
 - You can start with a lower rates if you expect to get more work from
   the same client in the future.
 - Consider market rates,if you are a starter it is better to start at
   reasonable/cheaper rate.
 - Your quote should cover all related expenses for the particular job.
   In case you took any additional help, cover that as well*

**2. Add part of the subcription charges to your quote, as you will re-use it, and not just for this perticular job.**

**3. Those eCommerce solutions are in business for years, so they can cut their profit by giving discounts to attract more customers.**